# method with String and no arguments

Tags: java

I need to write a public method costMultiplier() that takes no arguments and returns a double. The method should return 1.2 for postcodes beginning “WC1A” or “EC1A”, and 1.0 otherwise. without creating a class!

This is what I have so far but I have added an argument. I am not sure how to answer the question without the argument and how would I test ir accurately. Many thanks

```
public double costMultiplier(final String postCode) {
    double multiplier = 1.0d; `

    String pc = postCode.trim().toUpperCase(); 

    if (pc.startsWith("WC1A") || pc.startsWith("EC1A")) {
        multiplier = 1.2; 
    }

    return multiplier;
}
```

or I did this but need to include a String???

```
public static double costMultiplier(){    
    if(postCode.contains("WC")){    
       return 1.2; 
   }     
   else if(postCode.contains("EC"){
       return 1.0;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is for some assignment.

What you need to do is declare a property in a class like this.

```
public class Address {
    public String postCode;

    public double costMultiplier() {
          // do your calculations, took some code just as an example
          double multiplier = 1.0d; `

          String pc = this.postCode.trim().toUpperCase(); 

          if (pc.startsWith("WC1A") || pc.startsWith("EC1A")) {
              multiplier = 1.2; 
          }

         return multiplier;
    }
}
```

Now in your main function

```
 Address addr = new Address();
 addr.postCode = "somepostcode";
 // this is how you return the value
 addr.costMultiplier();
```

Comment: You could use a constructor